# counting employee attendance

Tags: sql, count

I am trying to write a statement for counting the employees attendance and execute their `id` , `name` and the days that he has working on the last 3 months by counting the duplicate `id` on `NewTimeAttendance`  for month 1, 2 and 3.

I tried to count:

```
Select COUNT(employeeid)
  from NewTimeAttendance
 where employeeid=1 and (month=1 or month = 2 or month = 3)
```

This is absolutely working, but just for one employee.

The second try:

```
SELECT COUNT(NewEmployee.EmployeeID)
  FROM NewEmployee INNER JOIN NewTimeAttendance 
    ON NewEmployee.EmployeeID = NewTimeAttendance.EmployeeID
   and (month=1 or month =2 or month = 3)
```

This is working, but it counts all employees and I want it to execute each `EmployeeId`, `EmployeeName` and `number of days` as new record.

Last try: (before you see the code ... it is wrong ..but I am trying)

```
for i in  0..27 loop
   SELECT COUNT(NewEmployee.EmployeeID),NewEmployee.EmployeeId,EmployeeName
     FROM NewEmployee INNER JOIN NewTimeAttendance 
       ON NewEmployee.EmployeeID(i) = NewTimeAttendance.EmployeeID
      and (month=1 or month =2 or month = 3)
end loop
```

I really need help...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` function, try:

```
SELECT COUNT(NewEmployee.EmployeeID), NewEmployee.EmployeeId,EmployeeName
 FROM NewEmployee INNER JOIN NewTimeAttendance 
  ON NewEmployee.EmployeeID = NewTimeAttendance.EmployeeID
   and (month=1 or month =2 or month = 3)
GROUP BY NewEmployee.EmployeeID, EmployeeName
```

Comment: You're going to need to put EmployeeName in your groupBy statement as well, I think.

Comment: @Paddy, thanks you are correct. I have updated my answer accordingly.