# How can I use two or more COUNT()s in one SELECT statament?

Tags: sql, join, count

i develop this code:

```
SELECT COUNT(NewEmployee.EmployeeID), NewEmployee.EmployeeId,EmployeeName 
FROM NewEmployee INNER JOIN NewTimeAttendance  
  ON NewEmployee.EmployeeID = NewTimeAttendance.EmployeeID 
  and NewTimeAttendance.TotalTime is  null 
  and (NewTimeAttendance.note = '' or NewTimeAttendance.note is null)
  and (month = 1 or month = 2 or month = 3)  
GROUP BY NewEmployee.EmployeeID, EmployeeName
order by EmployeeID
```

from my previous two questions **[selecting null stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452783/executing-null-values-records)** and **[counting issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447009/counting-employee-attendance)**...that amazing code is working beautifully fine..but now i need to `select` more than one `count`...

...searched (google) .... found `alias`...tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(NewEmployee.EmployeeID) as attenddays, COUNT(NewEmployee.EmployeeID) as empabsent
 , NewEmployee.EmployeeId,EmployeeName 
 FROM NewEmployee INNER JOIN NewTimeAttendance  
  ON empabsent =NewEmployee.EmployeeID = NewTimeAttendance.EmployeeID 
  and NewTimeAttendance.TotalTime is  null 
  and (NewTimeAttendance.note = '' or NewTimeAttendance.note is null )
    and (month=1 or month =2 or month = 3) , 
    attenddays = NewTimeAttendance.EmployeeID 
  and NewTimeAttendance.TotalTime is  null 
  and (NewTimeAttendance.note = '' or NewTimeAttendance.note is null )
    and (month=1 or month =2 or month = 3)
GROUP BY NewEmployee.EmployeeID, EmployeeName  order by EmployeeID
```

**`Incorrect syntax near '='.`**

second try:

```
SELECT COUNT(NewEmployee.EmployeeID) as attenddays, COUNT(NewEmployee.EmployeeID) as absentdays,
NewEmployee.EmployeeId,EmployeeName 
FROM NewEmployee INNER JOIN NewTimeAttendance  
  ON attenddays(NewEmployee.EmployeeID = NewTimeAttendance.EmployeeID 
  and NewTimeAttendance.TotalTime is  null 
  and (NewTimeAttendance.note = '' or NewTimeAttendance.note is null )
  and (month=1 or month =2 or month = 3)) ,
  absentdays(NewEmployee.EmployeeID = NewTimeAttendance.EmployeeID 
  and NewTimeAttendance.TotalTime is  null 
  and (NewTimeAttendance.note = '' or NewTimeAttendance.note is null )
  and (month=1 or month =2 or month = 3))
GROUP BY NewEmployee.EmployeeID, EmployeeName  order by EmployeeID
```

**`Incorrect syntax near '='.`**

not very good ideas...  so ...help

**all i want is to `count` the  ids with diferent conditions...**

```
COUNT(NewEmployee.EmployeeID)
ON NewEmployee.EmployeeID = NewTimeAttendance.EmployeeID 
  and NewTimeAttendance.TotalTime is  null 
  and (NewTimeAttendance.note = '' or NewTimeAttendance.note is null )
  and (month=1 or month =2 or month = 3)
```

**and**

```
COUNT(NewEmployee.EmployeeID)
ON NewEmployee.EmployeeID = NewTimeAttendance.EmployeeID 
  and NewTimeAttendance.TotalTime is not  null 
  and (NewTimeAttendance.note = '' or NewTimeAttendance.note is null )
  and (month=1 or month =2 or month = 3)
```

**in the same select statment.**

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to find out how many days each employee was in attendance and absent. I would recommend a query like this:

```
SELECT EmployeeId, EmployeeName,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM NewTimeAttendance
     WHERE NewTimeAttendance.EmployeeID = NewEmployee.EmployeeId
         /* include condition for employee in attendance */
         AND TotalTime IS NULL
         AND (Note = '' or Note IS NULL)
         AND Month BETWEEN 1 AND 3) AS AttendDays,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM NewTimeAttendance
     WHERE NewTimeAttendance.EmployeeID = NewEmployee.EmployeeId
         /* include condition for employee absent */
         AND TotalTime IS NULL
         AND (Note = '' or Note IS NULL)
         AND Month BETWEEN 1 AND 3) AS AbsentDays
FROM NewEmployee
ORDER BY EmployeeID
```

Comment: wooow..you understood me ..thanks for that..and very good coding too..thanks for that ... you know ... i was thinking about two select but i used alias.. you are very smart....thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first query throws a syntax error because of a bunch of errors in the ON clause. To wit:

```
1. empabsent =NewEmployee.EmployeeID = NewTimeAttendance.EmployeeID 
2. and (month=1 or month =2 or month = 3) , attenddays = NewTimeAttendance.EmployeeID
```

In the second query, are `AttendDays` and `AbsentDays` supposed to be user-defined functions? If they are, I cannot imagine that syntax working in any dialect of SQL.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? You want to counts of what? Can you provide two different SQL statements that independently give you the counts you want and then we might try combining them?

**EDIT** Given the new information you should be able to do this in a single query:

```
SELECT EmployeeId, EmployeeName
    , Sum(Case When NewTimeAttendence.TotalTime Is Null Then 1 Else 0 End) As AttendDays
    , Sum(Case When NewTimeAttendence.TotalTime Is Not Null Then 1 Else 0 End) As AbsentDays
FROM NewEmployee
    Join NewTimeAttendence
        On NewTimeAttendence.EmployeeId = NewEmployee.EmployeeeId
Where (NewTimeAttendence.Note = '' Or NewTimeAttendence.Note Is Null)
    And Month In(1,2,3)
Group By EmployeeId, EmployeeName
```